# Space time cube producing false zeros

Tags: arcgis-pro, space-time-cube

I tried creating a space time cube using "create space time cube from defined locations" using a 1 day time step interval just to create a 3D visual. it runs successfully but the output has a creates cubes with values of zero for the dates of "missing data" the data set is composed of data across three years but only of January, February and parts of March. Is there a way to set this up so that I don't have to query out the zero data?  [image]